# PostgreSQL equal aggregate

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

I'd like to check that all (float) values of a set of records are equal.
Something like

```
SELECT ..., equal(my_field) FROM my_table WHERE ... GROUP BY ...
```

Where `equal(my_field)` returns `true` if all values of `my_field` are equal.

Comment: `count(distinct my_column) = 1`. But `float` is an approximate data type, so you might get the correct count that you expect. For details see: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use MIN and MAX aggregates

```
SELECT min(field)=max(field) WHERE ... GROUP BY...
```

This doesn't take into account NULL values though. If those may be in the column you have to add a check for that.

Also remember that with floats equality is not always simple to check.